# Adding year and leading zeroes in id

Tags: php, php-7.1

I have column named ID and I want it to indicate year that record when it was created with format.

**Scenario**

```
I created new data on this day( 1-11-2019) and with the format.

2019-01-110000-1
```

And when it is reached to 9 it will become 0000-00010

Example:

```
20190101-0000-0001
...
20190101-0000-0010
```

**View**

```
<?= $purchase_order->date . sprintf("%06s",-$counter) ?>
```

Question: How can I add leading zeroes in 0000-1(it should be like this 0000-0001 and when it reached 9 it will become 0000-0010

Comment: I would create a function that counts the amount of characters in the number, and adds the necessary numbers in front of it, handling it as a string. And then adding the whole to your date.

Answer (score 0):

Math.

```
function weirdNumberFormatter(int $input) {
    $high = intdiv($input, 10000);
    $low  = $input % 10000;

    return sprintf('%04d-%04d', $high, $low);
}

var_dump(
    weirdNumberFormatter(1),
    weirdNumberFormatter(1234),
    weirdNumberFormatter(12345),
    weirdNumberFormatter(1234567),
    weirdNumberFormatter(12345678)
);
```

Output:

```
string(9) "0000-0001"
string(9) "0000-1234"
string(9) "0001-2345"
string(9) "0123-4567"
string(9) "1234-5678"
```